# Unexpected coefficients from Spark multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression, multinomial

I run Spark 2.1.1 on my Mac, OS Sierra (should this be helpful). I tried to fit a multinomial logistic regression on a test dataset I found online, I report here the first few lines (I don't know how to attach the file here):

```
1,0,24
1,0,26
1,0,26
1,1,27
1,1,27
3,1,27
```

The first column is the label ('brand', values: 1, 2, 3), the second and third columns are the features ('sex' and 'age').

Since the label have 3 classes, the multinomial logistic regression should perform 3 binomial models and then choose the predictions from the one which maximizes the probability of being in that class. So I expect the model to return a 3x2 coefficientMatrix: 3 because the classes are 3, and 2 because the features are 2. [This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multinomial-logistic-regression) documentation seems to be coherent with this point of view.

But, surprise surprise...

```
>>> logit_model.coefficientMatrix
DenseMatrix(4, 2, [-1.2781, -2.8523, 0.0961, 0.5994, 0.6199, 0.9676, 0.5621, 1.2853], 1)
>>> logit_model.interceptVector
DenseVector([-4.5912, 13.0291, 1.2544, -9.6923])
```

The coefficientMatrix is 4x2, and I have 4 intercepts rather than 3. Even stranger is this:

```
>>> logit_model.numClasses
4
```

For some strange reason, the model "feel" 4 classes, even if I have just 3 (see code below for a check on this).

Any suggestion?
Thank you very much.

---

Here is the full code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
from pyspark.ml import classification as cl
from pyspark.ml import feature as feat

customSchema = t.StructType(
    [t.StructField('brand', t.IntegerType(), True),
    t.StructField('sex', t.IntegerType(), True),
    t.StructField('age', t.IntegerType(), True)]
)

test_df01 = (
    spark
    .read
    .format('csv')
    .options(delimiter=',', header=False)
    .load('/Users/vanni/Downloads/mlogit_test.csv', schema=customSchema)
)

va = (
    feat.VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(['sex', 'age'])
    .setOutputCol('features')
)
test_df03 = (
    va
    .transform(test_df01)
    .drop('sex')
    .drop('age')
    .withColumnRenamed('brand', 'label')
)

logit_abst = (
    cl.LogisticRegression()
    .setFamily('multinomial')
    .setStandardization(False)
    .setThresholds([.5, .5, .5]) # to be adjusted after I know the actual values
    .setThreshold(None)
    .setMaxIter(100) # default
    .setRegParam(0.0) # default
    .setElasticNetParam(0.0) # default
    .setTol(1e-6) # default
)

logit_model = logit_abst.fit(test_df03)
```

Here is the check that the classes are just 3:

```
>>> test_df03.select('label').distinct().orderBy('label').show()
+-----+
|label|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing strange going on here. Spark assumes that labels are consecutive integer values, represented as `DoubleType`, and starting with 0.

Since the largest label you get is 3, Spark assumes that labels are actually 0, 1, 2, 3 - even if 0 never occurs in the dataset.

If this behavior is undesired you should re-encode labels to be zero-based, or apply `StringIndexer` on the raw labels.

Comment: Thank you very much, I replaced the class 3 with 0 and it worked! I would never have guessed such a solution.